# UITableView scrolls itself

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I've a weird problem with a UITableView. At the top of the tableview is a UISearchBar that I hide at viewDidLoad with

```
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake( 0, self.searchBar.frame.size.height );
```

Everything works fine, if the UITableView has enough cells, so that is scrollable. However, if there are only a few cells, sometimes my tableview scrolls itself to the bottom. It happens when I interact with the cells (theres a button on the contentview) or if I load another modal viewcontroller.

I suspect that Autolayout has something to do with it, but I don't really know where I should start looking.

Here are two screenshots to illustrate my problem.

This is the tableview at viewDidLoad.

[image]

This is my tableview after the unwanted scrolling occurs:

[image]

Comment: What you exactly need?

Comment: I want the tableview to stop scrolling itself. When I load a modal viewcontroller and dismiss it, the tableview suddenly has another scrollposition and of course I don't want this behaviour.

Comment: @DanielStein did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your tableview doens't have paging enabled

```
self.tableView.pagingEnabled = NO
```

or go to your storyboard and uncheck **Paging Enabled** on the attributes inspector of your tableView